# Looking for the proper Latin phrasing of "Man's defender"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I was looking for the proper way to convey the idea of someone being a defender of people's rights,freedoms, and safety.  In this context "Man" would be the same as "mankind" or "people."  Maybe "Defender of the people" would be a more proper phrasing in English, but I was looking for something more concise.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my ears, *defensor hominum* would mean someone who defended the existence of human beings. For the political aspect, I'd go with *defensor populi*, nicely paralleling such concepts as *vox populi*. For the "people" as state, look no further than Rome's motto: *Senatus *Populusque* Romanus*, or even Cicero's *res publica res populi*.

See the Lewis and Short entry on [**populus**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpopulus1).

I'd also second fdb's note of *vindex*, giving you **vindex populi** as the best way to convey what you want to say in Latin.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking out time to answer so thoughtfully; it is much appreciated.  The motto is for a project of my brother's, and we were initially leaning toward "Denfensor Hominis" before I posted the question.  I think I will now advise him to use "Defensor Populi."  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

One standard title for British monarchs is *dēfēnsor fideī*, "defender of the faith". So in reference to that I'd take *dēfēnsor* as your first word. And the standard word for "of men" (as in "humans", not "adult males") is *hominum*. So I'd say ***dēfēnsor hominum***.

(You can include the macrons, the little bars over some vowels, or omit them. They represent a pronunciation distinction that disappeared in later Latin.)

Answer (score 4):

"Defensor" is certainly not wrong, but I think "vindex" somehow sounds more Roman. See the quotations here:

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvindex

Comment: When I hear *vindex* I always think of an avenger rather than a defender, meaning II in L&S.

Answer (score 2):

(Adding this as a separate answer since it's very different from my first one.)

If you are interested in using Greek instead of Latin, the word ***Ἀλέξανδρος*** (*Alexandros*; *Alexandrus* in Latin) literally means "defending men" or "defender of men". It was an epithet of the goddess Hera as well as a name, made famous by Alexander the Great.

Comment: ....but it refers only to male men (viri not homines).

Comment: @fdb True. I've heard the divine epithet usage translated as "defender of humans" but I've never seen anēr used to mean humans in general; might be an epic thing?

Comment: @fdb ἀνήρ, especially in compounds, can include women; e.g. see [ἀνδροφάγος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=androfagos&la=greek#lexicon).

Comment: @cmw Maybe. But I don't think that either the quotation from Homer or that from Herodotus is unambiguous. The Cyclops at least is only explicitly described as eating men. *Hner- in the meaning "male" is in any event inherited from IE; cf Skt nar- vs. manuṣa-.

Comment: @fdb Albanian *njeri* was generalized to refer to "human, person." I deleted the earlier comment and transferred it to Draconis' new question.